# Is there anyway to do this in 1 line in a list comprehension?

Tags: python

The return on the map is a generator of lists. I want to turn it into a single list. This works but I want to know if I can do this in a single line of code in a list comprehension.

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    dirs = []
    for workers in executor.map(partial_subdirs, prefix_list):
        for w in workers:
            dirs.append(w)
```

I already tried, this doesn't append the lists into 1 list but instead creates a list of lists:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    dirs = [(f + f) for f in executor.map(partial_subdirs, prefix_list)]
```

Comment: There's two loops in the first sample, but only one loop in the second.

Comment: `[w for workers in executor.map(partial_subdirs, prefix_list) for w in workers]`

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't think of this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list.extend` to get rid of the inner loop:

```
dirs = []
for workers in executor.map(partial_subdirs, prefix_list):
    dirs.extend(workers)
```

Or for a one-liner *(and probably the most efficient)* use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain
dirs = list(chain.from_iterable(executor.map(partial_subdirs, prefix_list)))
```